# java.lang.NullPointerException when adding data to sqlite

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting Nullpointerexception error when checked rdio4
Codes:

Answerpage.java

```
    package com.example.psikotestproject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AnswerPage extends Activity{

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {


        super.onDestroy();
    }

DbHelper dbhelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Context contextim;


        int i=1;
        int obko=0;
        int soma=0;
        int kadu=0;
        int depr=0;
        int foan=0;

        static float somahesap=0.0f;
        static float obkohesap=0.0f;
        static float kaduhesap=0.0f;
        static float deprhesap=0.0f;
        static float foanhesap=0.0f;


        //dizim
        final String questions[]={
                "Baş ağrısı" ,
                "Sinirlilik ya da içinin titremesi",
                "Zihinden atamadığınız tekrarlayan, hoşa gitmeyen düşünceler",
                "Baygınlık ya da baş dönmesi",
                "Cinsel arzu ve ilginin kaybı",
                "Başkaları tarafından eleştirilme duygusu",
                "Herhangi bir kimsenin düşüncelerinizi kontrol edebileceği

    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.answerpage);

    //component tanımları
    final TextView txtquestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtquestion);
    final RadioGroup rdiogroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rdiogroup);
    final RadioButton rdio0=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdio0);
    final RadioButton rdio1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdio1);
    final RadioButton rdio2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdio2);
    final RadioButton rdio3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdio3);
    final RadioButton rdio4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdio4);
    final Button btndigersoru=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btndigersoru);
    final Button btnoncekisoru=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnoncekisoru);

    txtquestion.setText(questions[i-1]);


    //diğersorubutonclick

    btndigersoru.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
if(rdio0.isChecked()||rdio1.isChecked()||rdio2.isChecked()||rdio3.isChecked()||rdio4.isChecked())
{
            txtquestion.setText(questions[i]);


            if(rdio0.isChecked()==true)
            {
                dbhelper.addKayitlar(rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //secili[i]=rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rdiogroup.clearCheck();


            }

            if(rdio1.isChecked()==true)
            {
                if(i==1||i==4||i==12||i==27||i==40||i==42||i==48||i==52||i==53||i==56||i==58)
                    soma++;
                if(i==3||i==9||i==10||i==28||i==38||i==45||i==46||i==51||i==55||i==65)
                    obko++;
                if(i==6||i==21||i==34||i==36||i==37||i==41||i==61||i==69||i==73)
                    kadu++;
                if(i==4||i==5||i==15||i==20||i==22||i==26||i==29||i==30||i==31||i==32||i==54||i==71||i==79)
                    depr++;
                if(i==13||i==25||i==47||i==50||i==70||i==75||i==82)
                    foan++;

                dbhelper.addKayitlar(rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //secili[i]=rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rdiogroup.clearCheck();

            }
            if(rdio2.isChecked()==true)
            {
                if(i==1||i==4||i==12||i==27||i==40||i==42||i==48||i==52||i==53||i==56||i==58)
                    soma=soma+2;
                if(i==3||i==9||i==10||i==28||i==38||i==45||i==46||i==51||i==55||i==65)
                    obko=obko+2;
                if(i==6||i==21||i==34||i==36||i==37||i==41||i==61||i==69||i==73)
                    kadu=kadu+2;
                if(i==4||i==5||i==15||i==20||i==22||i==26||i==29||i==30||i==31||i==32||i==54||i==71||i==79)
                    depr=depr+2;
                if(i==13||i==25||i==47||i==50||i==70||i==75||i==82)
                    foan=foan+2;

                dbhelper.addKayitlar(rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //secili[i]=rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rdiogroup.clearCheck();
            }

            if(rdio3.isChecked()==true)
            {
                if(i==1||i==4||i==12||i==27||i==40||i==42||i==48||i==52||i==53||i==56||i==58)
                    soma=soma+3;
                if(i==3||i==9||i==10||i==28||i==38||i==45||i==46||i==51||i==55||i==65)
                    obko=obko+2;
                if(i==6||i==21||i==34||i==36||i==37||i==41||i==61||i==69||i==73)
                    kadu=kadu+2;
                if(i==4||i==5||i==15||i==20||i==22||i==26||i==29||i==30||i==31||i==32||i==54||i==71||i==79)
                    depr=depr+2;
                if(i==13||i==25||i==47||i==50||i==70||i==75||i==82)
                    foan=foan+3;

                dbhelper.addKayitlar(rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //secili[i]=rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rdiogroup.clearCheck();

            }
            if(rdio4.isChecked()==true)
            {
                if(i==1||i==4||i==12||i==27||i==40||i==42||i==48||i==52||i==53||i==56||i==58)
                    soma=soma+4;
                if(i==3||i==9||i==10||i==28||i==38||i==45||i==46||i==51||i==55||i==65)
                    obko=obko+4;
                if(i==6||i==21||i==34||i==36||i==37||i==41||i==61||i==69||i==73)
                    kadu=kadu+4;
                if(i==4||i==5||i==15||i==20||i==22||i==26||i==29||i==30||i==31||i==32||i==54||i==71||i==79)
                    depr=depr+4;
                if(i==13||i==25||i==47||i==50||i==70||i==75||i==82)
                    foan=foan+4;



                dbhelper.addKayitlar(rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

                //secili[i]=rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rdiogroup.clearCheck();
            }


        }

        if(i<16)
            i++;
        else{}

            if(i>1)
            {
                btnoncekisoru.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }


                if(i>=9)
            //if(i>=90)
            {   
                //En son hesaplar   
                somahesap=(float) (soma/11.0);
                obkohesap=(float) (obko/10.0);
                kaduhesap=(float) (kadu/9.0);
                deprhesap=(float) (depr/13.0);
                foanhesap=(float) (foan/7.0);

                Intent finishingActivity=new Intent("com.example.psikotestproject.RESULTPAGE");
                startActivity(finishingActivity);
            }



        }

    });

    //btnoncekibutonclick

    btnoncekisoru.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            rdiogroup.clearCheck();
            dbhelper.getKayitlar(i-1);
            txtquestion.setText(questions[i-1]);


            i--;

            //rdiogroup.check(secili[i]);

            if(i<=0)
            {
                btnoncekisoru.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    

            }

        }

    }); 


}
```

Dbhelper.java

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Tüm Static değişkenler
    // Database Versiyonu
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Adı
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbSecimler";

    // Kayitlar Tablosunun Adı
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Secimler";

    // Kayitlar Tablosunun Kolon Adları
    private static final String KEY_CEVAP = "Cevaplar";

    // Yapılandırıcı metod
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Database Oluşturma işlemi.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_table = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRİMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" 
                + KEY_CEVAP + " INTEGER," + ")";

        db.execSQL(create_table);
    }

    // Database Yükseltme işlemi.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Varsa şayet eski tabloyu sil.
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        // Tekrar tablo oluştur.
        onCreate(db);
    }


// Yeni Kayıt Eklemek.
void addKayitlar(int i) {
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CEVAP, i);

    // Ekleme işlemi...
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null , values);
    db.close(); // Açık olan database i kapat.
    }



//İstenilen Kaydı Getirmek.
Kayitlar getKayitlar(int i) {
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

 Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {KEY_CEVAP},null, null, null, null, null);
 if (cursor != null)
     cursor.moveToFirst();

 Kayitlar kayit = new Kayitlar(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
 // return Kayitlar
 return kayit;
}

}
```

Errors on LogCat

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat com.example.psikotestproject.AnswerPage$1.onClick(AnswerPage.java:282)
-
-
-
```

and 282 is: dbhelper.addKayitlar(rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
rdiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() not null I'm sure.I think I have an error about saving database.What can I solve?

Comment: It's pretty impossible to tell from this code what object is null or how it got that way, but rdioGroup is the first object I'd check if it were my code.

Comment: We need the code of your Activity/Fragment to help you. Here we don't know if you correctly get rdiogroup.

Comment: OK I have copied my activity's full code.
When I was recording a int array there wasnt any error.It throwed error when I started use database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing `findViewById()` for the view for which you have implemented `onClickListener`.

Comment: No.views are properly defined.There must be another problem